# Power BI R Script RegEx Only Returns First Match

Tags: r, regex

I have dirty data that contains mac addresses in Power BI and have learnt R today so that I can use a regular expression to extract them all. I can get everything working but it only returns the first mac address. If the data contains multiple (which they all do) they don't get returned.

I would like to return all the mac addresses into a new column as a list so that within Power query I can extract them to new lines.

Here is my Power Query code form within Power Query Editor.

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script

# Variables
pattern <- "([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|([0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\.[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\.[0-9a-fA-F]{4})"

# Functions
getMacs <- function(x) {paste(unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x))))}

# Return
output <- within(dataset,{MACs1=getMacs(dataset$NICs)})
```

Here is a sample value from a row of the NICs column.

```
: -kdnic-[00000000] Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
11:22:33:44:55:66 : 10.0.0.0; Realtek Gaming 2.5GbE Family Controller
22:33:44:55:66:77 : -Netwtw08-[00000002] Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz
33:44:55:66:77:88 : -vwifimp-[00000003] Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
44:55:66:77:88:99 : -vwifimp-[00000004] Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 : -BthPan-[00000005] Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
 : -RasSstp-[00000006] WAN Miniport (SSTP)
 : -RasAgileVpn-[00000007] WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
 : -Rasl2tp-[00000008] WAN Miniport (L2TP)
 : -PptpMiniport-[00000009] WAN Miniport (PPTP)
 : -RasPppoe-[00000010] WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
55:66:77:88:99:00 : -NdisWan-[00000011] WAN Miniport (IP)
66:77:88:99:00:11 : -NdisWan-[00000012] WAN Miniport (IPv6)
77:88:99:00:11:22 : -NdisWan-[00000013] WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
88:99:00:11:22:22 : -VPPP-[00000014] Virtual PPP Adapter"
```

What I get returned into my new Macs1 column is the very first mac address from the NICs column of each row. I can't for the life of me figure out how to return all of the mac addresses as a list.

I have verified using Visual Studio Code that the regex works and that the R code does return all mac addresses as a character vector.

[R Script Variable Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6YxC.png)

Doing some research I believe I need to convert the character vector to a list before returning it to Power BI. I tried amending the following lines without success.

```
output <- within(dataset,{MACs1=as.list(getMacs(dataset$NICs))})
output <- within(dataset,{MACs1=as.data.frame(getMacs(dataset$NICs))})
```

I know it's going to be some #newbieFail but I just can't seem to figure it out. Appreciate any pointers or advice.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`regmatches` returns a list like you want, but you then `unlist()` it inside your function. Later, when you use `as.list()` the information of which string goes in which list item has already been lost, so you get a list of the wrong size.

The fix is to get rid of your `paste(unlist())` and use the list returned by `regmatches`:

```
getMacs <- function(x) {regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x))}

data = data.frame(string = c(x, x))
data$macs = getMacs(data$string)
data$macs
# [[1]]
# [1] "11:22:33:44:55:66" "22:33:44:55:66:77" "33:44:55:66:77:88" "44:55:66:77:88:99" "55:66:77:88:99:00"
# [6] "66:77:88:99:00:11" "77:88:99:00:11:22" "88:99:00:11:22:22"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "11:22:33:44:55:66" "22:33:44:55:66:77" "33:44:55:66:77:88" "44:55:66:77:88:99" "55:66:77:88:99:00"
# [6] "66:77:88:99:00:11" "77:88:99:00:11:22" "88:99:00:11:22:22"
```

---

(Calling your string `x`):

```
x = ": -kdnic-[00000000] Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
11:22:33:44:55:66 : 10.0.0.0; Realtek Gaming 2.5GbE Family Controller
22:33:44:55:66:77 : -Netwtw08-[00000002] Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz
33:44:55:66:77:88 : -vwifimp-[00000003] Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
44:55:66:77:88:99 : -vwifimp-[00000004] Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
: -BthPan-[00000005] Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
: -RasSstp-[00000006] WAN Miniport (SSTP)
: -RasAgileVpn-[00000007] WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
: -Rasl2tp-[00000008] WAN Miniport (L2TP)
: -PptpMiniport-[00000009] WAN Miniport (PPTP)
: -RasPppoe-[00000010] WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
55:66:77:88:99:00 : -NdisWan-[00000011] WAN Miniport (IP)
66:77:88:99:00:11 : -NdisWan-[00000012] WAN Miniport (IPv6)
77:88:99:00:11:22 : -NdisWan-[00000013] WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
88:99:00:11:22:22 : -VPPP-[00000014] Virtual PPP Adapter"
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying data strucutres. I removed the paste(unlist() like this 

# Functions
getMacs <- function(x) {regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x))}

# Return
output <- within(dataset,{macs=getMacs(dataset$NICs)})

but that errors with 
We cannot convert this value from its .RData representation.

I then tried to cast the list to a data.frame like this 
output <- within(dataset,{macs=as.data.frame(getMacs(dataset$NICs))})

which I believe is the only format PBI supports but I get this error. 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 8, 5, 4

Comment: I am not sure how to perform these steps from your example from within the R function as the function is operating on each row of the dataset. 
data = data.frame(string = c(x, x))
data$macs = getMacs(data$string)
data$macs

Comment: My `data` is my best guess as to what your dataset looks like. If that's not what your data looks like, please share an example of a few rows of data, not just a single entry.

Comment: Hey Gregor I have a flat table with multiple columns computerName, ipAddress, NICs, purchaseDate, age etc. The data source is an excel spreadsheet and I read the data in using Power Query. I then have a step to run an R Script which is the script I have pasted above. I am unclear how to include the multiple steps you provided within the function getMacs <- function(x) {paste(unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x))))}?

Comment: Here is a quick screen shot of the table [link](https://imgur.com/r6FTtzu)

Comment: Here is a quick screen shot of the PQ prior to the R Script running. [link](https://imgur.com/NCWaDnn)